# Mailto using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

I'm new to javascript and the following code isn't working:

```
<script>
function sendMail()
{
    var yourMessage = document.getElementById("message").value
    var subject = document.getElementById("selectList").value
    var mail="mailto:chrisgreg23@googlemail.com?subject="+subject+"&body="+yourMessage;

    window = window.open(mail, 'emailWindow')
}
</script>
```

I just want a mail client window to open with the subject and body already done.

Help?

EDIT:

I've also tried this:

```
<script>
function sendMail()
{
    var yourMessage = document.getElementById("message").value
    var subject = document.getElementById("selectList").value
    var mail="mailto:chrisgreg23@googlemail.com?subject="+subject+"&body="+yourMessage;

    $(this).attr('href', mail);
}
</script>
```

Ive got that now, still not working.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? That said, it's possible that this can't be done at all using `window.open()`. In that case you'd have to use a link

Comment: I edited my post, still not working.

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/CJTgf/

Comment: window.location = mail is better than window.open because it won't invoke any popup blockers a la chrome..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code should look like this instead:

```
<script>
function sendMail()
{
    var yourMessage = document.getElementById("message").value;
    var subject = document.getElementById("selectList").value;
    document.location.href = "mailto:chrisgreg23@googlemail.com?subject="
        + encodeURIComponent(subject)
        + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(yourMessage);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This helped me so much. Thank you very much

Comment: This doesn't appear to work on the latest version of chrome. Setting location.href, using window.open() or using jquery attr('href') with a mailto: link does nothing.